# How to show a chart (line series) starting from zero?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, data-visualization

I'm using DataVisualization from WPF Toolkit.

I'm using LineSeries to show the data in the graph. But there's an inconvenience.

Is possible that the line start in zero? I have drawed a red line, I'd like to show it.

This is the code what I'm using:

```
            <ChartTools:Chart x:Name="SubobjectivesChart" Background="LightSteelBlue">
                <ChartTools:Chart.Axes>
                    <ChartTools:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True"  Minimum="0" Maximum="1" />
                </ChartTools:Chart.Axes>

                <ChartTools:Chart.Series>
                    <ChartTools:ColumnSeries Title="Exam" ItemsSource="{Binding Subobjectives}" Background="Black" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Exercise}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Average}" >
                    </ChartTools:ColumnSeries>
                </ChartTools:Chart.Series>
            </ChartTools:Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add another date with value 0 at the beginning of your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not and it shouldn't be possible. Chart is just a visual representation provider for your data. Just change your data accoridngly by rounding it down.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be true for WPF, but using the Forms designer I found an `IsMarginVisible` property for my project.  It's under `ChartArea > Axis > Scale`.

Although, I may not be fully understanding the question.  If you really want it to go to zero, there is an "EmptyPointValue" option under `Series > Misc > CustomPropertes`.  Could set that to "Zero".